# Creating Avro Schema without Class(-Object)

Tags: hadoop, schema, avro, kite, avsc

At the moment i'm serializing a class to an avsc schema. This works pretty good:

```
DatasetDescriptor desc = new DatasetDescriptor.Builder().schema(ClassName.class).build();
```

But, I need to create an AVSC **without any given class** dynamically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can create a schema on the fly or read an avro schema. The following code use hardcoded schema but is basically the same idea

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{\"namespace\": \"example.avro\",\n" +
        " \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
        " \"name\": \"User\",\n" +
        " \"fields\": [\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"favorite_number\",  \"type\": [\"int\", \"null\"]},\n" +
        "     {\"name\": \"favorite_color\", \"type\": [\"string\", \"null\"]}\n" +
        " ]\n" +
        "}");
DatasetDescriptor desc = new DatasetDescriptor.Builder().schema(schema).build();
```